Can't achieve NSButton behavior like in macOS Quicklook
Quicklook contain this button:
Idle:

Hover:

Active:

Can't achieve it with any settings, closest look I've got is having Idle and Active states, but on hover nothing is happening:
let button = NSButton(title: "Test", target: nil, action: nil)
button.bezelStyle = .toolbar
button.isBordered = true


According to Accessibility Inspector it's a NSSegmentedCell.

@Willeke: NSSegmentedCell is the parent, leaf element is a NSAccessibilitySegment (AXRole: AXButton, AXSubrole: AXSegment)

@soundflix I know, but I didn't think that would be very helpful. The button is probably a NSSegmentedControl with 1 segment.
